# How to push ViewController from outside of UIViewController or view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to be able to **navigate views from classes (singletons) in my app that have no connection to the views**. The reason for this is that the data changes (for example as a result of networking calls) at some point after finishing displaying the views. For example the app (some class) may only know after one second if the user has opened the app before and should go to the main view, or see some onboarding view.

---

I have a `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` as the starting point of my app. The business logic is kept separate from the view part in Manager singletons that look like:

```swift
class ExampleManager: NSObject {
    
    static var shared: ExampleManager = ExampleManager()
    
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        
        SwiftSingletons.register(self)
    }
}
```

like this I can cross-communicate between them. Now let's say in one of the functions of this ExampleManager -1 second after its initialisation- the managers knows (implicitly by data) to navigate to view A or B. But **how can I trigger a navigation to one of those views from within this manager?**

---

I suspect this could either be done the following ways:

- using combine / notifications (observing the data inside the ViewController)

  - problem: this feels like a workaround for something very simple..
- using a static function inside the `ViewController` which can be called externally

  - problem: `navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)` is not possible, since *"Instance member 'navigationController' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"*
- or maybe there is some way like `@ObservedObject` in SwiftUI that triggers the view / ViewController to recalculate when data changes?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I would highly recommend you look into the coordinator pattern! It works in the same way that you're trying to use these singletons.

You give a VC a "coordinator" (just an object) and it handles navigating between views/VCs. The VCs themselves don't actually know who's connected to who, but the coordinator handles that.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps

To answer your question more directly, you'd give your object `ExampleManager` access to a navigationController or view controller, and it will handle pushing / popping, but it doesn't know exactly which view it's going to / from. (See the link I dropped above)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I looked into it at it is definitely something I will keep in mind for this project. However, I feel like passing a reference of some NavigationController / ViewController to my data models / managers feels not clean enough. I am trying to *fully* separate view and business logic. Still, your answer is useful in that it helps to separate view navigation from view / view controllers, which is nice as well.

Comment: Also, the reason I am using this singleton pattern is that I even separate the business logic into multiple classes (managers). In order not to have the pain of passing / injecting references or thinking about ownerships of these instances I use singletons.

Comment: I didn't explain the coordinator pattern too well (see the article for how it's done to inject the actual navigation part). Also I think you'll like this video by Swift by Sundell, for using controllers (objects) to separate view and business logic https://youtu.be/Ni70aTksJWg